# List of path arrows in GAP

Tags: gap, computational-algebra, quiver

I am using the QPA package with GAP and have the following problem:

> I want to, given a path $p$, obtain a list (preferably ordered) of the arrows which make up $p$.

For example, if I have arrows $a,b,c$ in a path algebra $kQ$ and I have the path $p=ab$, I want the list $[a,b]$ to be returned from some function where I only have to input the path (and maybe the path algebra).

I did some digging and only found such a function for the quiver but not the path algebra: 3.7-4 in https://folk.ntnu.no/oyvinso/QPA/qpa/doc/chap3_mj.html#X7C8294338676C80E is a "WalkOfPath" function which returns such a list, but this only works for paths seen as paths in the quiver instead of paths seen as elements of a path algebra. There also does not appear to be a way to take a path of a path algebra and convert it back to a path in the quiver.

Any feedback is appreciated, cheers.

**Edit:** I have made a function which produces an unordered list of the arrows in a path, however this does not display them in the order in which they appear in the path (the latter would be better, so I am leaving the question open to answering). Also, my function does not include arrow multiplicities, which is something I really want out of it. Here is my function:

```
patharrows := function(pathalg, path)
 local i, arrows, output, rels, ideal;
 if path=Zero(path) then
    return [];
 fi;
 arrows := NthPowerOfArrowIdeal(pathalg, 1);
 output := [];
 for i in [1..Length(arrows)] do
    rels := [arrows[i]];
    ideal := Ideal(pathalg, rels);
    if \in(path, ideal) then
        Add(output, arrows[i]);
    fi;
 od;
 return output;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alas! I scanned the QPA manual and missed the following gem:

```
 LeadingMonomial(elem)
```

where `elem` is an element of the path algebra (call it $kQ$ with $Q$ being the quiver and $k$ the ground field). This function returns the tip of `elem` with respect to the given ordering for the Groebner basis calculations as a path in the quiver $Q$ rather than an element of the path algebra $kQ$. In particular, the tip of any monomial (regardless of the admissible ordering) is the monomial itself, and so if you input a monomial element of $kQ$ as `elem` then `LeadingMonomial(elem)` is the same monomial element regarded as a path in the quiver $Q$.

Now that we can play with our monomial element of $kQ$ as a path in $Q$, we can use the function

```
 WalkOfPath(path)
```

by setting `path := LeadingMonomial(elem)` and this function returns an **ordered list of the arrows appearing in `path`**. If you then want to interpret the arrows in this ordered list as elements of the path algebra $kQ$ rather than arrows in $Q$ (which is what the above does), you can use

```
 ElementOfPathAlgebra(kQ, path)
```

which embeds `path` into $kQ$.

Comment: Its amazing what a look into the manual can find (Variation on Westheimer's discovery: https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Frank_Westheimer).

Comment: Along the same line, in my work experience the manual was often sardonically referred to (especially when recommending its reading to newcomers) as 'the book of revelation'.